# Facebook like box working on Chrome, but not, IE or Firefox

Tags: facebook, iframe

I created a facebook like box and put it at the bottom of the website at familydentalheathonline.com, it works for me in Chrom, but now Firefox or IE... I am using Iframe for it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'd double check that you don't have an add-on installed that's causing the problem.  AdBlockPlus will occasionally treat it as a pop-up and block the content in Firefox for sure.  I would suggest disabling all add-ons while testing.  You can go to your menu button, then help (?) -->restart with add-ons disabled.

I'd also clear your browser cache and cookies.

Check that the iframe is using / (forward slash)... not \ (backslash).

Also, I've read that FF doesn't render iframes on Windows XP up to at least version 9.x

Comment: I do not have any addons on firefox or IE. Just Chrome, which is what I use all the time. I will check the forward slash, and also I am on Windows 7. Are you having any issues seeing the Facebook like box on the website in either IE or FF?

Comment: The only iframe I see is your video... including in Chrome.  Paste your code.

Comment: How do I paste code in this forum? What are the guidelines on that?

Comment: <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Ffamilydentalhealth&amp;width=240px&amp;height=195&amp;colorscheme=dark&amp;show_faces=true&amp;header=false&amp;stream=false&amp;show_border=true&amp;appId=235069019863702" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:240pxpx; height:195px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>

Comment: That is the code, I spaced in 4 spaces like you sent but it didnt work?